# Ошибка x is not a function при вызове функции в axios.then

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, type-error

Столкнулся с неожиданной проблемой. Есть компонент с формой и кнопкой:

```
<PrimaryButton onClick={this._handleSubmit} text="Add" />
```

При нажатии вызывает:

```
    _handleSubmit = () => {

        // Проблема тут
        this.props.loadCustomersAction()

        var self = this
        axiosWithProgress.post(
            '...AddCustomer.php',
            { name: this.state.name, mail: this.state.mail },
            { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } }
        ).then((response) => {
            if (response.data.error) self.setState({ error: response.data.error })
            else self.setState({ error: undefined })
            if (response.data.success === true) {
                self.setState({ hideDialog: true })
            }
        })
    }
```

Вызываемая функция:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        loadCustomersAction: () => dispatch(loadCustomers())
    }
}
```

Redux экшн:

```
export function loadCustomers() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axiosWithProgress.get(`...LoadCustomers.php`)
      .then(r => {
        const customers = r.data.customers
        dispatch({
          type: 'LOAD_CUSTOMERS',
          customers: customers
        })
      })
  }
}
```

Но все это не работает и выдает ошибку:

```
TypeError: _this.props.loadCustomersAction is not a function
```

Аналогичный механизм в другом компоненте работает отлично. Перепробовал множество вариантов из первых строк поисковика.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    return {
        loadCustomersAction: () => dispatch(loadCustomers())
    }
})
```

Скобки забыл: `const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({});`